# Generate create table script for Oracle from SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration, oracle-data-integrator

We are working on migration project and need to create table script for Oracle from SQL Server tables.
Is there anyway we can automate the process of creating these SQL server tables in Oracle.

Comment: I see ODI as a tag, are you using it as part of the project? If so it could help.
Which version of ODI do you use? Which version of Oracle DB?

Comment: There's a migration tool in SQL Developer, which is designed when you are fully migrating from SQL Server to Oracle, but one of the phases is transforming DDL so that could be of assistance here